# What is the difference between phylogroup and subclade?

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics, phylogenetics

Looking for clarification in terminology, examples would be greatly appreciated!

Not sure how this is off-topic. It is a general question about the difference between biological concepts defined in the field of bioinformatics.

"Questions are from students, academics and active researchers in biology and closely related fields, including:

- general questions about biological concepts
- questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions
- questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

Questions on interdisciplinary subjects like bioinformatics are also welcome, as long as they focus on the biological part of the subject."

Comment: The homework policy, which is linked to in the close reason, should tell you why people voted to close your question.

Comment: @canadianer this isn't homework ..... I genuinely do not understand the difference. Not taking any courses right now.

Comment: First off, I didn't vote to close. Second, some people around here have decided that "homework" includes any question that the asker does not show effort in researching themselves. This is in the homework policy as: *"A question that addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals"*. The policy also directs you to *"Research it yourself "*.

Comment: PS: If you think this question was unjustly closed, you can create a post on [meta].